# perl open: how to forward stderr to stdout?

Tags: perl, stdout, stderr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you capture stderr, stdout, and the exit code all at once, in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109124/how-do-you-capture-stderr-stdout-and-the-exit-code-all-at-once-in-perl)
>   [Capturing the output of STDERR while piping STDOUT to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132804/capturing-the-output-of-stderr-while-piping-stdout-to-a-file)

I am using the following piece of code to execute a process:

```
open( my $proch, "-|", $command, @arguments );
```

Unfortunately, I will just read the *stdout*. But I'd like to read the *stderr* as well.

Stderr redirection leads to the following error:

```
open( my $proch, "2>&1 -|", $command, @arguments );
>>> Unknown open() mode '2>&1 -|' at file.pl line 289
```

How can I forward *stderr* to *stdout*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2>&1` is part of a shell command, but you didn't execute a shell.

```
open( my $proch, "-|", 'sh', '-c', '"$@" 2>&1', '--', $command, @arguments );
```

If you want to avoid spawning the extra process, you could use the following:

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

open local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
my $pid = open3(
   '<&CHILD_STDIN',
   \local *PROCH,
   undef, # 2>&1
   $command, @arguments
);

while (<PROCH>) { ... }

waitpid($pid, 0);
```